# General properties of specific 12-node planar graph

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I have the following 12-node planar undirected graph:

[image: A planar 12-node graph]

Can this particular graph be said to belong to any defined family of graphs? Is it perhaps part of a discrete continuum of graphs?

It is (obviously) not the complete $K_{12}$, and it is not regular as 4 and 8 vertices have degree 4 and 3, respectively. The only thing I can see structurally, is that it seems to be a combination of three kinds of cycle graphs: $3 \times C_3$, $1 \times C_4$, and $1 \times C_6$.

Can anything interesting be said about it? Rotational symmetry?

I add tags on algebraic and spectral graph theory, since these fields are also of interest. Anything goes.

PS: No, this is not homework. Just tired of looking at this drawing :-)

Comment: Not sure what type of answer you're looking for, but for a start it's connected and Hamiltonian?

Comment: It is the skeleton of a Johnson solid: the square cupola.

Comment: Thanks. This might be a very good starting-point. I was of course hoping for these great multi-paragraph answers that get hundreds of upvotes. But I will take this too :-)

Comment: @Ole Thomsen Buus: Try to find its automorphism group.